# Can't minimize the browser's window when maximazed

Tags: firefox, chromium, 23.04

The browsers' (Firefox, Chromium & Edge) window can only be minimized when I click on the "Restore Down" (when the window is smaller). Otherwise the minimize button is not clickable. And also when I position the window into a segment, all of the upper-right corner buttons aren't clickable:

The segment, when non are clickable:

[image: the segment]

Position 2; can be minimized but not closed or maximized:

[image: Position 2]

Position 3, can't be closed:

[image: Position 3]

Position 4, I can minimize, maximize and close:

[image: Position 4]

What can be done?

Ubuntu Version: 23.04,
Gnome Version: 44.3,
Kernel version: Linux 6.2.0-26-generic,
Windowing System: Wayland

<strike>This issue is only present in the browsers.</strike>

**EDIT**: This is also present with the Visual Studio Code's window.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, though I'm on 23.10. Do you have extensions to Gnome Shell (if yes try disabling them) or particular PPAs?

Comment: Thank you @nteodosio your suggestion was relevant, I think the program was the AnyDesk (like Teamviewer). I uninstalled it, restarted my computer, and now the minimize is working!

Comment: Great that that helped, you are welcome!